# Group by Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Quiero solucionar un problema con pandas para convertir un dataframe resumido a diccionario
El dataframe es un resultado del groupby

```
response = pd.DataFrame(response).groupby(['unique_id','sku','name']).sum('quantity')
```

y me lo devuelve así

```
                             quantity
unique_id                            sku        name
dbfb411a-ff57-47e5-97e4-017ec7fcd996 2          Pantalones       5.0
```

Mi intención es devolverlo así

```
unique_id                            sku        name             quantity
dbfb411a-ff57-47e5-97e4-017ec7fcd996 2          Pantalones       5.0
```

Comment: Utiliza el argumento `as_index = False`

Comment: Gracias @HeytalePazguato. Eso era lo que me faltaba.